# How to edit a redirecting page of SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, internet-explorer, redirect

I have a page in SharePoint which redirects to another page out of domain (after some modifications in URL). I need to change the URL the page is redirecting to.

When i try to edit the page in browser it redirects me to that target page. Is there any way i can stop redirection for a while, make my changes and then continue? Redirection code is written by some other guy who is no longer in hand.

Any thoughts please?

Regards

Comment: You can check the redirection code of this page in SharePoint designer or Visual Studio, modify/remove it.

Comment: Not opening in Designer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three ways in my mind if you are using an embedded JavaScript to redirect.

**1.** Use SharePoint Designer to Edit the Page directly. Change your JavaScript code and save.

**2.** Export the page using SharePoint Designer, make changes as required and import again.

**3.** In your IE settings, disable JavaScript on your browser. No JS will render and you can edit your page using the default page edit option.

For future, i would suggest to keep your JS code separately and just include a reference of your JS file into your page specially when you are doing these type of operations like redirection.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The first option works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: 
if your URL is: `http://abc/default.aspx`, try adding `?contents=1` to that URL, so it reads:    `http://abc/default.aspx?contents=1`

You can now remove the interfering webpart.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the "Page Library" where the page is stored and choose Edit. (instead of first opening the page). That way the page will not open in "read mode" and thus not redirect you.

Comment: That is not an option to edit a page in SharePoint. You can edit properties, but not the page itself, from the Page Library.

Answer (score 0):

If you know c# and can use web part then please try,

```
Response.Redirect("your full url");
```

about [webparts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms432401(v=office.12).aspx)
about [redirecting page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: There is a JS Script that i have used in that page which is redirecting.